# PC not responding in Sleep Mode

Tags: dual-boot, suspend, touchpad

I have a PC in dual-boot Windows-Ubuntu where I use almost only Ubuntu. As described, if I put in Sleep Mode my PC, which is a SiComputer S.p.A. Nauta 01E, it doesn't wake up neither with the keyboard, nor with the touchpad or with the mouse.

This happens on a Windows 10 pro and in a Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. The only difference is in the mouse which reactivates the PC on windows but not on Ubuntu. Also, it works only if it was connected before entering the sleep mode. I've asked to the producer of the PC and it wasn't helpful at all, so I always have to force reboot when this happens.

I'm hoping here to find a solution, in order to not have to ship to the manufacturer the PC hoping for them to repairing, paying for that and losing the PC for some weeks. Also could not solve the problem on Ubuntu, I bought the PC with windows only.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Is this a laptop?

Comment: "Sleep" is what processes do, when they voluntarily surrender control. "Suspend" has the system save its state in RAM, and enter a reduced power state. "Hibernate" saves the system state to the swap area, and enters a lower power state. Which do you mean?

Comment: It's suspend mode, sorry. Yes it is a laptop.

Comment: Does it wake up when you press the power button momentarily?

Comment: No, there is no way, other than a mouse and this only in windows, to wake it up